# Subjonctif: “J'espère que vous appréciez” or “que vous appréciiez”?

Tags: grammaire, subjonctif, mode-grammatical

I saw this written as:

> J'espère que vous appréciez.

But I was under the impression that this is the subjonctif and thus should be:

> J'espère que vous appréciiez.

It seems to be written so often as the former though.

Comment: "appréciiez" can be *imparfait* too... and is so correct.

Comment: Appréciiez is correct as it is here because it is the subjonctif form? I was confused more by appréciez which is not the subjonctif form and is what was used in the sentence I came across.

Comment: espérer takes the subjunctive in the negative and interrogative. Not in the declararative. The same is true for penser.

Comment: So is this sentence a mistake or not: "Faire en sorte que l'apprentissage de la langue soit un hobby soit quelque chose que vous aimez faire, et que vous appréciez sans stress."  Should it be 'appréciez' here or in fact 'appréciiez'?

Comment: @Hasen, in your last comment "soit" is already a subjunctive, so what is to be (soit) here can be present here (aimez, appréciez). The subjunctive can be used too (aimiez, appréciiez), but I think that will reinforce the subjunctive aspect (used twice) and this is probably useless.

Comment: According to this http://conjugator.reverso.net/conjugation-french-verb-soit.html the subjonctif is "que je" or "qu'il" but here soit is isolated - why is  it then the subjonctif?

Comment: In "que l'apprentissage de la langue soit" you can put "il" instead of "l'apprentissage de la langue", which gives "qu'il soit". Anyway it is very hard for me to understand your example, perhaps because you have two "soit" and only one "que". Did you mean "either, or" or did you mean "be" ? Perhaps you meant "soit, soit un hobby, soit quelque chose que vous appréciez" (be either a hobby or something you like).

Answer (score 3):

*J'espère que* est le plus souvent suivi de l'indicatif dans une phrase affirmative au présent.

> J'espère que tu te rends compte de ton erreur.

Les subtilités de l'emploi du subjonctif sont parfois (très) complexes. Dans une phrase négative ou à un autre temps, le subjonctif serait généralement attendu.

> Si seulement nous avions le temps, j'espérerais que tu te rendes compte de ton erreur.

Il y a aussi d'autres constructions comme :

> Pour que j'espère que tu te rendes compte de ton erreur…

Mais le choix du mode dans des cas compliqués comme ça, c'est je crois une autre question, qui n'a malheureusement pas de réponse simple (voire pas de réponse tout court).

Dans le cas donné en exemple, il est exact qu'*appréciiez* serait la forme conjuguée à la deuxième personne du pluriel pour le verbe *apprécier* au présent du subjonctif (ainsi qu'à l'imparfait de l'indicatif). Mais, comme nous venons de voir, sans contexte, c'est le présent de l'indicatif qui est attendu dans cette phrase.
La phrase était donc correcte.

---

In a present-tense affirmative sentence, *J'espère que* is most often followed by a verb in its indicative form. For example:

> J'espère que tu te rends compte de ton erreur.
>   *I hope that you realize your mistake*.

The subtleties that underlie the use of the subjunctive can be (very) complex at times. In a negative sentence, or if the sentence were in a different tense, a verb in its subjunctive form would normally be expected.

> Si seulement nous avions le temps, j'espérerais que tu te rendes compte de ton erreur.
>   *If only we had the time, I would hope (expect) that you realize your mistake.*

We can also think of different constructions such as:

> Pour que j'espère que tu te rendes compte de ton erreur…
>   (lit.) *In order for me to hope that you realize your mistake…*

Choosing the right mood in difficult cases like these is, I think, beyond the scope of this question. There is no easy answer to that (quite possibly no answer at all).

In the example you provided, you rightfully point out that *appréciiez* would   be the correct second-person plural subjunctive form of *apprécier* (and it is also the imperfect indicative form). However, as mentioned above, without further context, the present indicative form is the one expected. It means that the original sentence was correct.

Comment: Ah, I just noticed I answered in French while the question was asked in English. I'll try to come up with a translation.

Comment: The full sentence was rather long but this is it: "Faire en sorte que l'apprentissage de la langue soit un hobby soit quelque chose que vous aimez faire, et que vous appréciez sans stress."

Comment: oui : *Pour que j'espère que vous appréciiez, il faudrait que je connaisse vous goûts. * Et dans la phrase longue *appréciiez sans stress*.

Comment: So it should be appréciiez and not appréciez in the sentence I gave? So it is in fact mistake?

Comment: @Hasen: No it's more likely at the same level as *aimer* (even though the comma might be misleading). In which case it should be indicative as well. There's no reason to think there's a mistake beside the spurious use of the comma. (One is also missing after *hobby*)

Comment: Ok I see. But jcm69 seems to have corrected the sentence to be "appréciiez". Seems to be a disagreement between you two?